# Could not find a declaration file for module 'highcharts' in version 11.0.0 and forward

Tags: typescript, highcharts, vuejs3

I am using Vue 3 with TypeScript and I am trying to import the types from highcharts with this line of code:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts'
```

If I use highcharts version `10.3.3` or prior, everything functions correctly. But from version `11.0.0` and onward it shows this error: `Could not find a declaration file for module 'highcharts'`. Am I doing something wrong or is the new version broken? I have also tested it with the latest version (`11.1.0`).

EDIT 2:

My config files seems to be irrelevant, since I started a new Vue 3 project from scratch by using `Vite`, imported `highcharts` and `highcharts-vue` packages and it still throws the same error. `highcharts-vue` works correctly, but the reqular `highcharts` is unable to find the module.

EDIT1:

Here are my config files:

(I deleted the config files since they were irrelevant)

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem, it looks like everything works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-worker-nlwjr2

Comment: @Michał Okay well in that case I have to take a look at your config files and package versions in your test project in order to pinpoint what is causing the problem. I will get back to this on Thursday, thanks for your input!

Comment: @Michał I tried using the config files and dependency versions that you had in your project, but it still shows the same error. I added my original config files to the question.

Comment: Same problem here.  Are you using VSCode?  I get the error in the IDE, but typescript builds it fine.  So it seems like yet another VSCode bug.  The d.ts file is 22mb, which seems crazy, maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: @Dirigible Yes I am using VSCode, sorry for forgetting to tell that. Errors like these are really driving me crazy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused in VSCode by the **Volar** extension which by default has **20MB** as a default `Max File Size` for `.vue` files.

To change that you should go to `File` -> `Preferences` -> `Settings` and change the `Vue: Max File Size` to a number above 25MB.

This seems to solve the problem.

Comment: I have the shims file, and I am importing highcharts in a ts file, not a vue file.  I still get the error.  My solution was to use highcharts v10.  The d.ts file is only 6mb instead of 22mb.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my answer and added why it might be the case for version 11. However I do not exclude the possibility of this issue being caused by the large .d.ts file size.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/19205#issuecomment-1666824632
There's already an issue in highcharts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).